# Tezos node error: node.worker: Context corruption detected: restoring integrity. This may take a while

Tags: node

I am getting this error on my node (v7.3) and it seems that after a while it fetches some new blocks and then again this error appears.

```
2020-08-20T03:20:37.815979782Z Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
 
2020-08-20T03:20:37.818105708Z Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
 
2020-08-20T03:20:37.819754492Z Updating the node configuration...
 
2020-08-20T03:20:40.701665933Z Aug 20 03:20:40 - node.main: starting the Tezos node (chain = TEZOS_MAINNET)
 
2020-08-20T03:20:40.701772072Z Aug 20 03:20:40 - node.main: disabled local peer discovery
 
2020-08-20T03:20:41.337465749Z Aug 20 03:20:41 - node.main: read identity file (peer_id = idsxxxxxxxxxx)
 
2020-08-20T03:20:41.337653930Z Aug 20 03:20:41 - main: shell-node initialization: bootstrapping
 
2020-08-20T03:20:41.415479591Z Aug 20 03:20:41 - main: shell-node initialization: p2p_maintain_started
 
2020-08-20T03:20:41.416432035Z Aug 20 03:20:41 - block_validator_process_external: Initialized
 
2020-08-20T03:20:41.418515271Z Aug 20 03:20:41 - block_validator_process_external: Block validator started on pid 228 
 
2020-08-20T03:20:47.151739751Z Aug 20 03:20:47 - node.worker: Context corruption detected: restoring integrity. This may take a while...
 
2020-08-20T03:28:57.063618861Z Aug 20 03:28:57 - node.main: Received the TERM signal, triggering shutdown.
 
2020-08-20T03:29:27.870867292Z Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
 
2020-08-20T03:29:27.874231059Z Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
 
2020-08-20T03:29:27.875028158Z Updating the node configuration...
 
2020-08-20T03:29:30.463471519Z Aug 20 03:29:30 - node.main: starting the Tezos node (chain = TEZOS_MAINNET)

...repeated infinitely
```

Comment: Your best solution here is to completely wipe your node's data dir and import a fresh snapshot. The context is not something you can fix with commands/scripts.

Comment: That's what I did, but the message clearly says "Context corruption detected: restoring integrity", which makes one believe that it's self-fixing

Comment: Well, if it was self-fixing then it would not be restarting over and over. Possibly you got a bad snapshot or corrupted import. I suggest a new snap from here https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/

Comment: No, the snapshot was not a problem. The node was working fine for over than 2 months

Comment: Well, if you didn't have an issue then, you certainly have one now. Check `dmesg` on your server for any disk IO errors and then do a new snap import to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sending a Ctrl-c each time as `node.main: Received the TERM signal, triggering shutdown.` suggests? If so, it means that you never let the node finish its recovery process...

Comment: @PierreBoutillier no I am not